# How to find coordinates of contraction of the tensor $T(\phi,\psi,u):=\phi (a)\psi (u)+\psi (a)\phi(u)$

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, dual-spaces

$\phi , \psi \in V^*$ and $u,a \in V$ and $a=(2,-1,3)^T$. I used $\{\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2,\varepsilon_3\}$ as canonical basis for $V$ and $\{\varepsilon^1,\varepsilon^2,\varepsilon^3\}$ as dual canonical basis. Then I solve
\begin{eqnarray*}
T^{ij}_k=T(\varepsilon^i,\varepsilon^j,\varepsilon_k)=\varepsilon^i(a)\varepsilon^j(\varepsilon_k)+\varepsilon^j(a)\varepsilon^i(\varepsilon_k)=a^i\delta^j_k+a^j\delta^i_k
\end{eqnarray*}
Now solving for tensor contractions
\begin{eqnarray*}
(C_{11}T)^i=T^{ji}_j=a^j\delta^i_j+a^i\delta^j_j=a^i+a^i\text{dim}V=4a^i\\
(C_{21}T)^i=T^{ij}_j=a^i\delta^j_j+a^j\delta^i_j=a^i\text{dim}V+a^i=4a^i
\end{eqnarray*}

I am stuck at this point. I don't really know how to move from this to the coordinates of the contractions. I don't know how to use components of $a$ here.

Since it is a type (2,1) tensor, it's contraction must always be (1,0) tensor. 
Does this mean that both contractions have coordinates $(8,-4,12)$?

Comment: you need 3 canonical $\varepsilon^s$ to work on $V$ which seems to be 3 dimensional in view of the data for $a$.

Comment: Fixed it, it was just a little slip. You're right, I am working in three dimensions.

Comment: you've $a=2\varepsilon_1-\varepsilon_2+3\varepsilon_1$.

Comment: you mistook when you did $\delta^j_j=3$. It's just $1$.

Comment: but it's $a^i\delta_j^j$ which is the same as $a^i$dim$V$ and dimension of $V$ is three, isn't that right?

Comment: No, I don’t see why.

Comment: I've been using this for a while now. I was sure it's correct. If you sum over j you should get three. $\sum^n_{j=1}\delta^j_j=3$ where n is the dimension of $V$. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: yes, you're right, I was distracted, excuse me